# Can I find two specific words with the same md5 hash?

Tags: hash, md5, collision-resistance

I want to find two strings containing special words like "yes" or "no", mixed with random characters, for which the MD5 hash is equal.

An example of what I'm looking for:

```
First string : YES/d6g45d78h74jfhcf     MD5 : 4cf349066ce85e0c947eb1d0c94c13b1
Next string  : NO/djf986f98edf8dfv4     MD5 : 7fdefd9bd8a46db9b48a323e8e366150
```

As you can see the MD5 hashes are different; Is it possible to change the random characters to get equal MD5 hashes?

Comment: here is a "meaningful" example of md5-collision: http://www2.mat.dtu.dk/people/S.Thomsen/wangmd5/meaningful.html

Comment: Look up the chosen prefix collision attacks on MD5. | The brute-force collsion attack Jon Hulka describes if far to expensive for the OP.

Comment: *I removed a bunch of comments and two answers which didn't really fit this site after the migration.*

Answer (score 12):

What you want is called a [chosen prefix collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack#Chosen-prefix_collision_attack). Given p<sub>1</sub>, p<sub>2</sub> you want to find m<sub>1</sub>, m<sub>2</sub> such that hash(p<sub>1</sub> || m<sub>1</sub>) = hash(p<sub>2</sub> || m<sub>2</sub>).

### Generic attack

The generic attack to find this, is creating messages starting with p<sub>1</sub> and just as many starting with p<sub>2</sub>. Thanks to the birthday problem you'll find a match after around 2<sup>n/2</sup> messages.

For a 128 bit hash like MD5, this means you need about 2<sup>64</sup> operations. This is feasible in principle, but exceeds your budget. I guess it costs 200'000\$ if you use GPUs and 5'000\$ if you already have developed appropriate ASICs.

### Exploiting MD5's weaknesses

MD5 is a broken hash function. Finding normal collisions is very cheap, but that doesn't help you. Luckily(for you) there is also a chosen prefix attack against MD5.

According to a [paper from 2009](http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-09/BEVAND/BHUSA09-Bevand-MD5-PAPER.pdf) this costs around 2<sup>51</sup> compressions. Which corresponds to to about 18 GPU days on a GPU that cost 200\$ in 2009.

So I estimate that the attack costs 10-20\$.

There are two caveats:

1. The random characters are no printable ASCII characters, but rather random bytes.

   It might be possible to modify the scheme to only emit printable ASCII, but I didn't investigate that.
2. There will be more random characters than your example has, probably somewhere between 70 and 130.